# Azure B2C - My customer would like to send the country code value on a custom claim he added on the custo policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I'm assisting a client which is working on a B2C custom claim. He has created the custom claim as scollarCountryCode, and would like to know if its possible to pull the country code attribute value and send this value in this custom claim.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your client has finished the steps in [Add claims and customize user input using custom policies in Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-configure-user-input).

So now you can get the custom attribute in [user interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-configure-user-input#add-a-claim-to-the-user-interface) and [token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-configure-user-input#include-a-claim-in-the-token).

If you want to query the custom attribute, just use Microsoft Graph API [Get a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http).

```
Get https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{id | userPrincipalName}
```

You can get the custom attribute in the response. Its format is like this:

```
"extension_8adbe99219ca4e689a5030b5af068847_scollarCountryCode": 00123
```

Please note `8adbe99219ca4e689a5030b5af068847` in this case is the client id of WebApp-GraphAPI-DirectoryExtensions, which is the built-in enterprise app in the B2C tenant. You will have a different one.